# Using a BufferedWriter in a static class

Tags: java, design-patterns, memory, io

I am making a class to handle Errors, called ErrorHandler
Please correct me if this is not the best practice.

However, considering just about every method is going to use a BufferedWriter, should I simply initialize it as a field?

```
private BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(errorFile));
```

I am concerned with memory leaks and resource usage, should I simply make it

```
private BufferedWriter output;
```

and initialize it/close it within every method, or is initializing it once okay?

Comment: Second will be more efficient then 1 but it also depend on the requirement.If only single method require bufferedWriter object then you can use first option inside the method.In second option you have to make sure about NPE

Comment: The problem of logging has been solved a thousand times. Why re-invent the wheel? It's pretty standard these days to use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/)

Comment: @Otanan how many methods are there?

Comment: @LanceJava Then why program? Just about every piece of software has been made. Actually, I guess for the learning experience, but I appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: @swapnil7 ~5, is there some sort of threshold minimum I should pass?

Comment: @otanan whilst you're implementing yet another logging framework I'll be writing code that someone actually needs ;)